# Send parameter from a report to another SSRS 2010

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, action

I would like to send parameter from a report1 to report2 in action of textbox (in report1), I found just tuto for sending parameter to Subreports.
Some help

Comment: Your question is off-topic, I'm sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both reports are located in the same project:

1. Select **Go to report** as the action for textbox in report 1
2. Select report 2 in the **Specify a report** dropdown
3. Click the **Add** button to create a new parameter mapping
4. Select the target parameter in report 2 in the **Name** column
5. Select the parameter you are sending from report 1 in the **Value** column, or create an expression that passes along the data you want to send.

That's it! Let me know if the reports are not co-located in the same project and I can send instructions on passing a parameter to report 2 via URL.